# Confusion On How To Implement Chatbot To GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, chatbot

I recently made a chatbot with Python and also GUI using Tkinter for my chatbot. But the problem is I have no idea on how to implement my chatbot into the GUI. Like I made the Chatbot and the GUI separately. I would really be grateful if you guys could help me. Here are Chatbot and GUI codes respectively below:

```
def start():
    print('start')
def second_window():
    root=Tk()
    root.title('welcome to metis')
    root.geometry('400x500')
    label2=Label(root,text='welcome to metis')
    button2=Button(root,text='hi').place(x=0,y=0)
    file_menu = Menu(root)
    main_menu = Menu(root)
    file_menu.add_command(label="New..")
    file_menu.add_command(label="Save As..")
    file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")
    main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)


    main_menu.add_command(label="Quit",command=root.quit)
    root.config(menu=main_menu)
    chatWindow = Text(root, bd=1, bg="black", width="50", height="8", font=("Arial", 23), foreground="#00ffff")
    chatWindow.place(x=6, y=6, height=385, width=370)
    messageWindow = Text(root, bd=0, bg="black", width="30", height="4", font=("Arial", 23), foreground="#00ffff")
    messageWindow.place(x=128, y=400, height=88, width=260)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=chatWindow.yview, cursor="star")
    scrollbar.place(x=375, y=5, height=385)
    sendphoto=PhotoImage(file='send.png')
    Button3= Button(root, text="Send", width="12", height=5,command=send,
                    bd=0, bg="#0080ff", activebackground="#00bfff", foreground='#ffffff', font=("Arial", 12))
    Button3.place(x=6, y=400, height=88)
    root.mainloop()

window=Tk()
window.geometry('500x497')
window.title('metis')
window.config(bg='blue')
bg=PhotoImage(file='rob111.png')
myimage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('png-format-16265000621410769899metis.png'))
label=Label(window,image=bg)
label.place(x=0,y=0)



icon=PhotoImage(file='rob111.png')
window.iconphoto(True,icon)
button1=Button(window,text='start',command=second_window).place(x=250,y=250)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: First thing, without even reading I can already tell that all this code is not necessary so please reduce it to [mre]. Also provide Your efforts at creating what You want (the combination part) and tell what exactly is the issue. EDIT: I read the question, still, provide a [mre]. If You want to know something about tkinter, here are the [tkinter docs (don't know if official)](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/)

Comment: Changing to a GUI requires changing the way you think.  A console app is very linear; you start at the top, and you go to the bottom.  GUI apps are all event-driven.  You set up the windows and present them, and then your part is done.  The GUI system will call your callbacks when things happen (button clicks, text changes, etc).  Your job becomes writing those callback functions to change the components of the GUI in response.

Comment: @Matiiss The only official docs that I know are the ones [here on python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html). But most of the time people don't find them useful so they go to unofficial docs like the one you posted and [this one here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)

Comment: @Matiiss & Tim Roberts Thank you! The thing is I studied Tkinter SEPARATELY from these youtube tutorials and creating a chatbot program SEPARATELY. This is mainly because there were not many instructors who demonstrated working with both. So as I said I know how to create a GUI like the templates & stuff but don't know how to implement the individually made chatbot into it :( Anyways thank you, Tim, for telling me how these stuffs work and thank you Matiiss for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tkinter module (python)

ex: label = Label(root, text="hi")

label.pack()

copy the tkinter snippet(available in google)